# When do I know I have to lock a dictionary in a c# base class?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to understand something about multi-threading in a C# application. I inherited an application that has the following code in a base class called SecurityComponentBase:

```
        m_permissionsLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            if (m_grantedPermissions.Count > 0)
            {
                m_grantedPermissions.Clear();
                m_loggingComponent.WriteSecurityLog(
                    "Security permissions cleared for user: " + CurrentLoggedUser.Username);
            }

            foreach (var p in permisions)
            {
                m_loggingComponent.WriteSecurityLog("Security permission: "+ p.PermissionName + " Granted to user: " + userName);
                m_grantedPermissions.Add(p.PermissionName, p);
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            m_permissionsLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
```

The m_permissionsLock is defined as:

```
private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim m_permissionsLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
```

The m_grantedPermissions is defined as:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, Permission> m_grantedPermissions = new Dictionary<string, Permission>();
```

When would a developer know that he *has* to wrap this dictionary in a lock? To me, I wouldn't even know where other threads would be coming from. Remember I'm new to this multi-threading thing. But how would I even know that I have to do this?

Comment: It's a private member variable - only your class can access it (unless you're handing it out via some other public property or method). Therefore you _do_ know how it's being accessed. If you want your class to be thread-safe, any methods that use your dictionary will need to lock appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When would a developer know that he has to wrap this dictionary in a lock?

We observe the following principles:

1. Get a **Write** lock when **modifying** the dictionary, or its contents, in any way.
2. Get a **Read** lock when **accessing** the dictionary or its contents, without modifying either.
3. **Control access** to the dictionary, so only *we* can access it, in this class.  Access to the dictionary must go through us.

Point #1 is demonstrated in the code you pasted.  Point #3 is also demonstrated in your code with the `private` declaration of `m_grantedPermissions`.  Only the code in this class can access the private member.

> To me, I wouldn't even know where other threads would be coming from.

Where calling threads come from isn't relevant.  When a thread executes code from this class, you, the developer, can spot where you are reading and writing the dictionary, and you can wrap each reference accordingly.  Remember, only *this class* can access the dictionary.  You don't need to search your entire solution.  Just the one class.

In Visual Studio, double-clicking the `m_grantedPermissions` should highlight every instance; you can also search for "m_grantedPermissions" to find every reference to it.

Each reference to `m_grantedPermissions` should be wrapped in the proper lock.

Comment: I understand that this is the only class accessing the dictionary, because it is private. So why do I have to protect it in a lock if this in the only class using it?

Comment: Because this classes methods may be called on different threads, at the same time.  If you read and write at the same time without properly locking, you'll have a bad time.  Suppose this class had public methods `A()`, `B()`, etc and each access the dictionary in some way.  **IF** it is possible they can be called concurrently, locking mechanisms must be put in place to ensure you don't try to read/write at the same time.

Comment: Contrast this with the dictionary being public.  Then, every time a programmer wants to use it, they have to lock it using the *same* locking mechanism (everyone has to use the same mechanism for it to work).  That gets very hairy very quickly, and is very difficult to **ensure safe concurrent access**.  That's the only reason you make it private.